# What to put in the fab to create cardviews - recyclerviews, adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have been following this tutorial right through with a few minor adjustments for my own use: [Android RecyclerView and CardView Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-recyclerview-cardview-tutorial/#Setting-Adapter-to-RecyclerView)

(The point of my app is when you press the fab, a `cardview` appears. Inside each `cardview` is a `spinner`, `edittext`, `textview` and `checkbox`.)

However I need to finally add some code into the FAB so that a `cardview` is added. But I am unsure how to do this with all  I have done with adapters. the tutorial asked me to do `productList = new ArrayList<>();` and so I could use `productList.add` but I don't know how to go on from there.

Here is the snippet of my main activity code:

```
FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =(FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        productList.add //what goes here???//
    }
});
```

And this is my current create.java code (which the above snippet is in)

```
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {

    //a list to store all the products
    List<Product> productList;

    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create);

        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);

        Product.spinnerItemsList = csvFile.read();

        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //initializing the productlist
        productList = new ArrayList<>();

        //TODO FAB BUTTON
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                productList.add //what goes here???//
            }
        });

        //creating recyclerview adapter
        ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList);

        //setting adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {
            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    //TODO I edited this part so that you'd add the values in our new hash map variable
                    /*
                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);
                    */
                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }
}
```

This is MyListAdapter.java which is for the Spinner.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    int groupid;
    List<String> items;
    Context context;
    String path;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int vg, int id, List<String> items) {
        super(context, vg, id, items);
        this.context = context;
        groupid = vg;
        this.items = items;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textid;
        public TextView textname;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        {
            View rowView = convertView;
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                rowView = inflater.inflate(groupid, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.textid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
                viewHolder.textname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            // Fill data in the drop down.
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            String row = items.get(position);
            //holder.textid.setText(row[0]); //prints aisle number, dont need

            holder.textname.setText(row);

            return rowView;
        }
    }
}
```

This is Product.Java from tutorial

```
public class Product {

    private String editText;
    private Boolean checkBox;
    private String textView5;

    public static List<String> spinnerItemsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Product(List spinner, String editText, Boolean checkBox, String textView5) {
        this.editText = editText;
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
        this.textView5 = textView5;
    }
    public String getEdittext () {
        return editText;
    }

    public boolean getCheckbox () {
        return checkBox;
    }

    public String getTextview () {
        return textView5;
    }
}
```

And this is ProductAdapter.java also from tutorial

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    //this context we will use to inflate the layout
    private Context mCtx;
    private Spinner spinner;

    //we are storing all the products in a list
    private List<Product> productList;

    //getting the context and product list with constructor
    public ProductAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Product> productList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.productList = productList;
    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflating and returning our view holder
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_products, null);
        return new ProductViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //getting the product of the specified position
        Product product = productList.get(position);

        //binding the data with the viewholder views

        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(mCtx, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, Product.spinnerItemsList);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        Spinner spinner;
        EditText editText;
        TextView textView5;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            textView5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            checkBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        }
    }
}
```

I've done the same xml stuff as the tutorial fyi.

EDIT

```
 final Spinner spinner;
      final EditText editText;
      final CheckBox checkBox;
      final TextView textView5;

      spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
      editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
      checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
      textView5 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);

      final ProductAdapter  adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList);

        //TODO FAB BUTTON
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);


        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



                Product mProduct = new Product(List spinner, String editText, Boolean checkBox, String textView5);
                productList.add(mProduct); //what goes here???//
                if(adapter != null)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //Handle the empty adapter here

            }
        });
```

layout_products.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp">


            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="159dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="36dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="89dp"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="34dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The way I see your code, The whole implementation is at a toss.

Comment: I probably got confused in the process of trying to add details for my spinner like the spinner adapter..

Comment: I understand, The tutorial is a pretty low quality.

Comment: Do you know of any tutorial that works with adding cardviews to recyclerview, dynamically? like when FAB is pressed?

Comment: You rarely get a particular Tutorial for a situation like that. You just have to make use of recyclerview efficiently, that's it. You can add an item to it from FAB, No problem.

Comment: If you can update your question with item xml file, I can provide you an Answer here.

Comment: I have added layout_products.xml in my post

Comment: Okay lemme do in my lappy, Give me some time, I'll post an answer here and update you asap.

Comment: thanks, I really appreciate it :) and if you are posting long code i appreciate any comments in them too

Comment: Okie Dokie No Problem..

Comment: Have you taken Basic Activity? or Blank Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Product Model with the following

```java
public class Product {

    private String editText;
    private Boolean checkBox;
    private String textView5;

   // The following list is useless unless u don't use it somewhere so lets create getters and setters for this item
   private List<String> spinnerItemsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Product(List spinner, String editText, Boolean checkBox, String textView5) {

        this.editText = editText;
        this.spinnerItemsList = spinner;
        this.checkBox = checkBox;
        this.textView5 = textView5;
    }
    public String getEdittext () {
        return editText;
    }

    public boolean getCheckbox () {
        return checkBox;
    }

    public String getTextview () {
        return textView5;
    }
    public String getSpinnerItemsList () {
        return spinnerItemsList;
    }
}
```

Well I think you just need to add a dummy object in your array list and then just call notifyDataSetChanged()

```java
//Step 1 reposition your adapter
        ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList);

        //TODO FAB BUTTON
        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //The problem is in the following line you need to pass the values but what you are doing is incorrect
                //Product mProduct = new Product(List spinner, String editText, Boolean checkBox, String textView5);
                //So replace the above line with the following code
            ArrayList<String> spinnerItem = new ArrayList<String>();
            spinnerItem.add("StackOverFlow");
                //There are better and efficient ways to achieve this, If you explain what do you want exaclty I might be able to help
                Product mProduct = new Product(spinnerItem, "EditText Value", true, "TextView Value");
                productList.add(mProduct); //what goes here???//
                if(adapter != null)
                  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                else
                  //Handle the empty adapter here

            }
        });
```

I guess now with the above code you are good to go!

**UPDATE** Try changing the following code block inside ProductAdapter.java

```java
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //getting the product of the specified position
        Product product = productList.get(position);

        //binding the data with the viewholder views


        //MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(mCtx, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, Product.spinnerItemsList);
        //spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        //Try using Simple ArrayAdapter if all you need to display is one text
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (mCtx, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Product.getSpinnerItemsList());
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter); 
    }
```

Comment: I have edited my above post at the bottom with what I have now. But for some reason it does not work..

Comment: it says I need commas or brackets on this line? `                Product mProduct = new Product(List spinner, String editText, Boolean checkBox, String textView5);
`

Comment: This is what the current activity code looks like. With the stuff I added in the fab code, you will see. https://pastebin.com/1ixr9UDL thanks

Comment: You said in comments to explain what i want the activity to do. well, when the user presses the fab I want a cardview to appear. Within that cardview is a spinner, edittext, textview and checkbox, all in a line, inside the cardview. When u press the fab again, cardview appears again, with those same elements inside it. when u press spinner, various elements from a csv file show. when you select an item from the spinner, the corressponding number to that item in the csv file appears in the textview in that same cardview. I think i've got that spinner textview thing sorted ?

Comment: So I got 2 errors. in my productadapter.java. here is there error from logcat https://pastebin.com/9jV899Gr at lines 16 and 50 which are `        `spinner.setAdapter(adapter);` << line 50 and this is line 16 >> `public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {`

Comment: any ideas? :) I aprecate ur help

Comment: thanks! What is the spinnerArray varialbe at the end of this line ```        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
```

Comment: Sorry you have to replace it with Product.spinnerItemsList, Check the updated answer.

Comment: thanks :) no problem. But for this part `(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Product.spinnerItemsList)` it now says  canot resolve constructor

Comment: Replace "this" with "mCtx", Check the updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180779/discussion-between-ussaid-iqbal-and-grand-skunk).

Answer (score 2):

`productList` is a list of products. You must supply an object of type `product` when doing `productList.add().

example:

```
floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Product p = new Product(...)
        productList.add(p);
        ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, productList);
        //setting adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
});
```

p.s: The first argument in the constructor of `Product` is useless as you aren't using it anywhere.

There are better ways of implementing this tho.

Comment: When you go new Product what do the... Mean?

Comment: In Product.java the constructor requires 4 arguments -   public Product(List spinner, String editText, Boolean checkBox, String textView5). So replace (...) with (<any-list>, <any-string>, <any-boolean>, <any-string>)

Comment: @GrandSkunk I suggest you thoroughly familiarize yourself with java before getting into android development.

Comment: But I have got a card view. Inside that is edit text TextView spinner and checkbox

Comment: a  new card appears when you click the FAB, correct?

Comment: well that's what is suppose to happen, yes (and inside each cardview are those said elements)

Comment: Why you are setting a new adapter all over again? When you can use notifyDataSetChanged()...

Comment: @UssaidIqbal Yes, notifyDataSetChanged() is better.